# I want to print a mathematics table of a specific number of user choice using functions in php

Tags: php

I want to print a mathematics table of a specific number of user choice using functions in php ..
I make a form using html which take a number as input from user and print this number specific mathematics table..
here is my HTML:

```
<div >
    <form action="" method="post">
        <h1>Enter A Number:</h1>
        <input type="number" name="no"/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</div>
```

and here is the PHP part:

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
{
    $no = $_REQUEST['no'];
    function table(){
        for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++){
        $tab = $no*$i;      
        echo $no." X ".$i." = ".$tab."<br />";  
        }
    }
    table();
}
```

problem is that how to pass user input to function??

Comment: what's the problem?

Comment: Please use global for $no under function.
function table(){
global $no;
        for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++){
        $tab = $no*$i;      
        echo $no." X ".$i." = ".$tab."<br />";  
        }

Comment: @sohanverma Oh **please dont**

Comment: No need for `global` ! Your function does not takes any argument, you need one and then pass `$no` to your function

Comment: can you please show me in code?

Comment: thanks its work perfectly for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare $no as a global variable in the function.

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
{
    $no = $_REQUEST['no'];
    function table(){
        global $no;
        for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++){
        $tab = $no*$i;      
        echo $no." X ".$i." = ".$tab."<br />";  
        }
    }
    table();
}
```

Or you can use a parameterized function like:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {
    $no = $_REQUEST['no'];
    table($no);
}

function table($no)
{
    for ($i=1;$i<=10;$i++) {
        $tab = $no*$i;
        echo $no." X ".$i." = ".$tab."<br />";
    }
}
```

Comment: To check the output you need to pass  submit and no in url or hardcode it in code. Check:https://3v4l.org/MQLOa and https://3v4l.org/BCom0

Comment: You are using $_REQUEST to get the inputs from user; you should be checking the URL like: http://localhost/mathtable.php?submit=1&no=3

Answer (score 2):

Define `table function` outside the `if` condition like below example and pass `$no` as a `parameter`

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
{
    $no = $_REQUEST['no'];

    table($no);
}
function table($no){
        for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++){
        $tab = $no*$i;      
        echo $no." X ".$i." = ".$tab."<br />";  
        }
    }
```

you can check your desired [output](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cb3cc11601b8a8da1a0bcd62d1acf27a811a6c81)

Comment: @OubaidMaher i have add output.. and again check (form is submit or not)

Comment: form is submit but no output

Comment: when i echo number outside the function it works but not pass value to function

Answer (score 2):

Add a parameter to your function and then pass the value in using that parameter

Also a good idea to check that the user entered a value before trying to use it.

```
<?php
function table($no)
{
    for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++){
        $tab = $no*$i;      
        echo $no." X ".$i." = ".$tab."<br />";  
    }
}

if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'], $_REQUEST['no']))
{
    table($_REQUEST['no']);
}
```

Comment: i did it but got no output

Comment: Check your `page source` on the browser, you may need to wrap the output in some HTML

Comment: page source is same when i echo value outside the function it works but when pass the value to function it shows no output

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function table($no){
    for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++){
    $tab = $no*$i;      
    echo $no." X ".$i." = ".$tab."<br />";  
    }
} 
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$no = $_POST['no'];
table($no);
}
?>
```

Comment: You might like to check that code one more time Mr Bond

Comment: @RiggsFolly yeah i saw i put the function last x_x

Comment: That does not actually matter, but the lack of an argument in the function does kinda matter

Comment: add parameter in function table

Comment: @RiggsFolly Oops dx_xb

Answer (score 0):

1. You can add a parameter to your function and then pass the value to the function

   ```
   function table($no){
       for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++){
           $tab = $no*$i;      
           echo $no." X ".$i." = ".$tab."<br />";  
       }
   }
   table($no);
   ```
2. You can also use global keyword inside function to access '$no'

   ```
   function table(){
       global $no;
       for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++){
           $tab = $no*$i;      
           echo $no." X ".$i." = ".$tab."<br />";  
       }
   }
   table();
   ```

Comment: And this adds **what** to the previous 4 answers, one of which is exactly that same as yours?